# Using functions.php for Elementor pages

Tags: php, wordpress, elementor

I'm struggling with something specific to elementor I believe. I'm trying to generate a different product grid thumbnail size on one particular category page. The category page is however not the standard woocommerce page but an Elementor template. I've tried a number of PHP/WordPress functions in functions.php but I was not able to check whether I'm on the particular category page or not. The logic was - if category x is currently displayed use thumbnails of a different size.
Do you have any ideas how I can achieve this? I think the usual functions don't work because it is an elementor page. I couldn't even grab the post id so that I can make an if statement based on it...

Maybe the questions is just broader - How can one work with functions.php and Elementor at the same time?

I followed this example I found: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/131358/how-to-change-the-thumbnail-size-to-a-specific-category but I couldn't get it to work or anything similar.

I believe changing the thumbnail size would not be a problem. **The challenge is how to do that only for one particular elementor template.**

Comment: Do you use elementor pro or free version?

Comment: @thốngnguyễn Hey, I believe it is the pro version. Even if it is not atm, we have the license so I can set it up. Does that make a difference?

Comment: Yes, it's difference. Elementor pro have built-in function for this - and it very easy to setup. I've record a guide video here: https://youtu.be/yqAuDd8pzPg Hope this help!

Comment: Hey, thank you very much for recording the video. I see your point and I know how to work with the templates but in your example you use "posts" and not the "products" section. The products section doesn't have this feature to change image size. Do you know how we should go about it? Is it about setting up the products to display as posts rather than using the products section?

Answer (score 0):

Because of lazy, i don't install woocommerce in my test site for [the guide video here](http://youtu.be/yqAuDd8pzPg). That why i used posts instead.

Your case, my friend. If you install woocommerce, in the elementor pro theme builder will have two tabs for products as image below. Please use Single Product and Products archive template:
[image]

And to change the grid query from posts to products. In the posts setting, query section - change source into products (if you want to only show the products in certain category, then set include by term and select the product category you want to display as below image):
[image]